# type 'Data' is not a subtype of type 'WeatherModel' in type cast in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch image from an api. For that I am using http package for flutter. I created List View Builder pattern to arrange the structure of the project. Here is the api link and response:

```
https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=Raleigh,NC&key=5cea02af6cd6498d9524cedb8ab23b4c
```

Response =>

```
{"city_name":"Raleigh","country_code":"US","data":[{"app_max_temp":23.8,"app_min_temp":12.6,"clouds":29,"clouds_hi":42,"clouds_low":10,"clouds_mid":20,"datetime":"2023-03-25","dewpt":14.8,"high_temp":25.1,"low_temp":14.4,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":23.8,"min_temp":12.6,"moon_phase":0.227104,"moon_phase_lunation":0.15,"moonrise_ts":1679750686,"moonset_ts":1679717316,"ozone":265.5,"pop":10,"precip":0.40685272,"pres":999.2,"rh":75,"slp":1009.5,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1679742625,"sunset_ts":1679787057,"temp":19.6,"ts":1679727660,"uv":5.3,"valid_date":"2023-03-25","vis":22.79,"weather":{"description":"Scattered clouds","code":802,"icon":"c02d"},"wind_cdir":"S","wind_cdir_full":"south","wind_dir":186,"wind_gust_spd":9.8,"wind_spd":5},{"app_max_temp":18,"app_min_temp":12.3,"clouds":59,"clouds_hi":28,"clouds_low":53,"clouds_mid":41,"datetime":"2023-03-26","dewpt":12.1,"high_temp":16.9,"low_temp":11.8,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":18,"min_temp":12.3,"moon_phase":0.321547,"moon_phase_lunation":0.18,"moonrise_ts":1679839308,"moonset_ts":1679807553,"ozone":280.4,"pop":60,"precip":3.2589798,"pres":1005.1,"rh":82,"slp":1015.8,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1679828938,"sunset_ts":1679873508,"temp":14.8,"ts":1679803260,"uv":2.4,"valid_date":"2023-03-26","vis":16.929,"weather":{"description":"Light shower rain","code":520,"icon":"r04d"},"wind_cdir":"SE","wind_cdir_full":"southeast","wind_dir":134,"wind_gust_spd":4.2,"wind_spd":2.2},{"app_max_temp":16.9,"app_min_temp":11.8,"clouds":92,"clouds_hi":63,"clouds_low":92,"clouds_mid":21,"datetime":"2023-03-27","dewpt":13.6,"high_temp":16.9,"low_temp":12,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":16.9,"min_temp":11.8,"moon_phase":0.420509,"moon_phase_lunation":0.21,"moonrise_ts":1679928256,"moonset_ts":1679897518,"ozone":282.6,"pop":55,"precip":2.6394958,"pres":1004.4,"rh":94,"slp":1014,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1679915252,"sunset_ts":1679959958,"temp":13.8,"ts":1679889660,"uv":2.4,"valid_date":"2023-03-27","vis":11.253,"weather":{"description":"Light shower rain","code":520,"icon":"r04d"},"wind_cdir":"SSE","wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","wind_dir":168,"wind_gust_spd":3.5,"wind_spd":1.9},{"app_max_temp":17.6,"app_min_temp":11.2,"clouds":84,"clouds_hi":85,"clouds_low":22,"clouds_mid":63,"datetime":"2023-03-28","dewpt":5.6,"high_temp":17.6,"low_temp":6.8,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":17.6,"min_temp":11.2,"moon_phase":0.519989,"moon_phase_lunation":0.25,"moonrise_ts":1680017554,"moonset_ts":1679987107,"ozone":297.5,"pop":20,"precip":0.0625,"pres":1005.7,"rh":58,"slp":1019.3,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680001565,"sunset_ts":1680046409,"temp":14.5,"ts":1679976060,"uv":2.5,"valid_date":"2023-03-28","vis":24.124,"weather":{"description":"Overcast clouds","code":804,"icon":"c04d"},"wind_cdir":"SSE","wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","wind_dir":162,"wind_gust_spd":2.3,"wind_spd":2},{"app_max_temp":17.6,"app_min_temp":5,"clouds":22,"clouds_hi":13,"clouds_low":22,"clouds_mid":0,"datetime":"2023-03-29","dewpt":2,"high_temp":17.6,"low_temp":7.6,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":17.6,"min_temp":6.8,"moon_phase":0.616791,"moon_phase_lunation":0.28,"moonrise_ts":1680107168,"moonset_ts":1680076271,"ozone":335.3,"pop":0,"precip":0,"pres":1006.8,"rh":54,"slp":1020.9,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680087879,"sunset_ts":1680132859,"temp":11.8,"ts":1680062460,"uv":7.9,"valid_date":"2023-03-29","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Scattered clouds","code":802,"icon":"c02d"},"wind_cdir":"ESE","wind_cdir_full":"east-southeast","wind_dir":117,"wind_gust_spd":2.7,"wind_spd":2.7},{"app_max_temp":19.5,"app_min_temp":7.6,"clouds":4,"clouds_hi":11,"clouds_low":1,"clouds_mid":1,"datetime":"2023-03-30","dewpt":1.7,"high_temp":20.7,"low_temp":12.5,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":20.7,"min_temp":7.6,"moon_phase":0.708213,"moon_phase_lunation":0.31,"moonrise_ts":1680197007,"moonset_ts":1680165027,"ozone":330.6,"pop":0,"precip":0,"pres":1012,"rh":49,"slp":1025.7,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680174192,"sunset_ts":1680219309,"temp":13.1,"ts":1680148860,"uv":8.3,"valid_date":"2023-03-30","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Few clouds","code":801,"icon":"c02d"},"wind_cdir":"SW","wind_cdir_full":"southwest","wind_dir":233,"wind_gust_spd":2,"wind_spd":2},{"app_max_temp":22.4,"app_min_temp":12.4,"clouds":96,"clouds_hi":57,"clouds_low":63,"clouds_mid":84,"datetime":"2023-03-31","dewpt":6.5,"high_temp":23.1,"low_temp":17.2,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":23.1,"min_temp":12.4,"moon_phase":0.791724,"moon_phase_lunation":0.35,"moonrise_ts":1680286963,"moonset_ts":1680253436,"ozone":278,"pop":50,"precip":3.0625,"pres":1008.3,"rh":51,"slp":1022,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680260506,"sunset_ts":1680305759,"temp":16.9,"ts":1680235260,"uv":8.4,"valid_date":"2023-03-31","vis":22.536,"weather":{"description":"Light rain","code":500,"icon":"r01d"},"wind_cdir":"SSW","wind_cdir_full":"south-southwest","wind_dir":201,"wind_gust_spd":3.9,"wind_spd":3.9},{"app_max_temp":23,"app_min_temp":16.9,"clouds":53,"clouds_hi":63,"clouds_low":38,"clouds_mid":51,"datetime":"2023-04-01","dewpt":12,"high_temp":23.3,"low_temp":15.8,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":23.3,"min_temp":16.9,"moon_phase":0.864742,"moon_phase_lunation":0.38,"moonrise_ts":1680376949,"moonset_ts":1680341581,"ozone":283.1,"pop":70,"precip":7.75,"pres":999.8,"rh":62,"slp":1013.3,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680346820,"sunset_ts":1680392209,"temp":19.6,"ts":1680321660,"uv":8.5,"valid_date":"2023-04-01","vis":22.96,"weather":{"description":"Moderate rain","code":501,"icon":"r02d"},"wind_cdir":"SW","wind_cdir_full":"southwest","wind_dir":219,"wind_gust_spd":4.9,"wind_spd":4.9},{"app_max_temp":21.4,"app_min_temp":14.4,"clouds":0,"clouds_hi":0,"clouds_low":0,"clouds_mid":0,"datetime":"2023-04-02","dewpt":9.3,"high_temp":21.9,"low_temp":11.6,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":21.9,"min_temp":14.4,"moon_phase":0.924578,"moon_phase_lunation":0.42,"moonrise_ts":1680466919,"moonset_ts":1680429544,"ozone":332.4,"pop":0,"precip":0,"pres":1007.3,"rh":58,"slp":1021.3,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680433135,"sunset_ts":1680478660,"temp":18,"ts":1680408060,"uv":8.5,"valid_date":"2023-04-02","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Clear Sky","code":800,"icon":"c01d"},"wind_cdir":"SW","wind_cdir_full":"southwest","wind_dir":226,"wind_gust_spd":4,"wind_spd":4},{"app_max_temp":22,"app_min_temp":11.6,"clouds":11,"clouds_hi":28,"clouds_low":3,"clouds_mid":5,"datetime":"2023-04-03","dewpt":8.1,"high_temp":22.7,"low_temp":11.4,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":22.7,"min_temp":11.6,"moon_phase":0.968524,"moon_phase_lunation":0.45,"moonrise_ts":1680556870,"moonset_ts":1680517400,"ozone":322.5,"pop":0,"precip":0,"pres":1003.9,"rh":59,"slp":1017.7,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680519449,"sunset_ts":1680565110,"temp":16.7,"ts":1680494460,"uv":8.6,"valid_date":"2023-04-03","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Few clouds","code":801,"icon":"c02d"},"wind_cdir":"SSW","wind_cdir_full":"south-southwest","wind_dir":204,"wind_gust_spd":3.4,"wind_spd":3.4},{"app_max_temp":19,"app_min_temp":11.4,"clouds":89,"clouds_hi":100,"clouds_low":81,"clouds_mid":89,"datetime":"2023-04-04","dewpt":7.7,"high_temp":19.8,"low_temp":12.3,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":19.8,"min_temp":11.4,"moon_phase":0.994039,"moon_phase_lunation":0.48,"moonrise_ts":1680646828,"moonset_ts":1680605221,"ozone":303.4,"pop":30,"precip":0.875,"pres":1002.5,"rh":63,"slp":1016.3,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680605764,"sunset_ts":1680651560,"temp":15.2,"ts":1680580860,"uv":8.7,"valid_date":"2023-04-04","vis":20.296,"weather":{"description":"Overcast clouds","code":804,"icon":"c04d"},"wind_cdir":"SSW","wind_cdir_full":"south-southwest","wind_dir":210,"wind_gust_spd":3.4,"wind_spd":3.4},{"app_max_temp":14.6,"app_min_temp":13.1,"clouds":100,"clouds_hi":100,"clouds_low":92,"clouds_mid":100,"datetime":"2023-04-05","dewpt":13.2,"high_temp":17.1,"low_temp":14.6,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":14.6,"min_temp":13.1,"moon_phase":0.998998,"moon_phase_lunation":0.52,"moonrise_ts":1680736842,"moonset_ts":1680693081,"ozone":295.9,"pop":90,"precip":17.1875,"pres":1000,"rh":97,"slp":1013.8,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680692079,"sunset_ts":1680738010,"temp":13.8,"ts":1680667260,"uv":8.7,"valid_date":"2023-04-05","vis":11.208,"weather":{"description":"Heavy rain","code":502,"icon":"r03d"},"wind_cdir":"E","wind_cdir_full":"east","wind_dir":97,"wind_gust_spd":4.1,"wind_spd":1.9},{"app_max_temp":23.6,"app_min_temp":15.7,"clouds":91,"clouds_hi":100,"clouds_low":1,"clouds_mid":91,"datetime":"2023-04-06","dewpt":12,"high_temp":24.2,"low_temp":11.8,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":24.1,"min_temp":15.7,"moon_phase":0.981938,"moon_phase_lunation":0.55,"moonrise_ts":1680823242,"moonset_ts":1680781057,"ozone":309.1,"pop":30,"precip":1.3125,"pres":995.5,"rh":66,"slp":1009.3,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680778395,"sunset_ts":1680824460,"temp":19.9,"ts":1680753660,"uv":8.8,"valid_date":"2023-04-06","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Overcast clouds","code":804,"icon":"c04d"},"wind_cdir":"WSW","wind_cdir_full":"west-southwest","wind_dir":244,"wind_gust_spd":12.9,"wind_spd":5.7},{"app_max_temp":15.7,"app_min_temp":11.8,"clouds":23,"clouds_hi":50,"clouds_low":10,"clouds_mid":6,"datetime":"2023-04-07","dewpt":2.8,"high_temp":15.7,"low_temp":5.9,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":15.7,"min_temp":11.8,"moon_phase":0.942278,"moon_phase_lunation":0.59,"moonrise_ts":1680913366,"moonset_ts":1680869244,"ozone":326,"pop":0,"precip":0,"pres":1000,"rh":48,"slp":1014,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680864711,"sunset_ts":1680910911,"temp":13.8,"ts":1680840060,"uv":8.9,"valid_date":"2023-04-07","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Scattered clouds","code":802,"icon":"c02d"},"wind_cdir":"NNW","wind_cdir_full":"north-northwest","wind_dir":327,"wind_gust_spd":8.9,"wind_spd":4.8},{"app_max_temp":14.8,"app_min_temp":3,"clouds":1,"clouds_hi":4,"clouds_low":0,"clouds_mid":0,"datetime":"2023-04-08","dewpt":-2.2,"high_temp":14.8,"low_temp":8,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":14.8,"min_temp":5.9,"moon_phase":0.880499,"moon_phase_lunation":0.62,"moonrise_ts":1681003645,"moonset_ts":1680957754,"ozone":312.6,"pop":0,"precip":0,"pres":1007.3,"rh":45,"slp":1021.3,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1680951027,"sunset_ts":1680997361,"temp":10.4,"ts":1680926460,"uv":9,"valid_date":"2023-04-08","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Clear Sky","code":800,"icon":"c01d"},"wind_cdir":"NNW","wind_cdir_full":"north-northwest","wind_dir":340,"wind_gust_spd":7.6,"wind_spd":3.9},{"app_max_temp":17.2,"app_min_temp":8,"clouds":25,"clouds_hi":81,"clouds_low":0,"clouds_mid":15,"datetime":"2023-04-09","dewpt":0.8,"high_temp":17.2,"low_temp":10.5,"max_dhi":null,"max_temp":17.2,"min_temp":8,"moon_phase":0.798277,"moon_phase_lunation":0.65,"moonrise_ts":1681094091,"moonset_ts":1681046713,"ozone":300.1,"pop":0,"precip":0,"pres":1011.5,"rh":46,"slp":1025,"snow":0,"snow_depth":0,"sunrise_ts":1681037344,"sunset_ts":1681083811,"temp":12.6,"ts":1681012860,"uv":9,"valid_date":"2023-04-09","vis":24.128,"weather":{"description":"Scattered clouds","code":802,"icon":"c02d"},"wind_cdir":"SSW","wind_cdir_full":"south-southwest","wind_dir":199,"wind_gust_spd":4.8,"wind_spd":2}],"lat":"35.7721","lon":"-78.63861","state_code":"NC","timezone":"America/New_York"}
```

Here is my Model

```
class WeatherModel {
  String? cityName;
  String? countryCode;
  List<Data>? data;
  String? lat;
  String? lon;
  String? stateCode;
  String? timezone;

  WeatherModel({this.cityName, this.countryCode, this.data, this.lat, this.lon, this.stateCode, this.timezone});

  WeatherModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    cityName = json['city_name'];
    countryCode = json['country_code'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    lat = json['lat'];
    lon = json['lon'];
    stateCode = json['state_code'];
    timezone = json['timezone'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['city_name'] = cityName;
    data['country_code'] = countryCode;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['lat'] = lat;
    data['lon'] = lon;
    data['state_code'] = stateCode;
    data['timezone'] = timezone;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  double? appMaxTemp;
  double? appMinTemp;
  int? clouds;
  int? cloudsHi;
  int? cloudsLow;
  int? cloudsMid;
  String? datetime;
  double? dewpt;
  double? highTemp;
  double? lowTemp;
  Null? maxDhi;
  double? maxTemp;
  double? minTemp;
  double? moonPhase;
  double? moonPhaseLunation;
  int? moonriseTs;
  int? moonsetTs;
  double? ozone;
  int? pop;
  double? precip;
  double? pres;
  int? rh;
  double? slp;
  int? snow;
  int? snowDepth;
  int? sunriseTs;
  int? sunsetTs;
  double? temp;
  int? ts;
  double? uv;
  String? validDate;
  double? vis;
  Weather? weather;
  String? windCdir;
  String? windCdirFull;
  int? windDir;
  double? windGustSpd;
  double? windSpd;

  Data(
      {this.appMaxTemp,
      this.appMinTemp,
      this.clouds,
      this.cloudsHi,
      this.cloudsLow,
      this.cloudsMid,
      this.datetime,
      this.dewpt,
      this.highTemp,
      this.lowTemp,
      this.maxDhi,
      this.maxTemp,
      this.minTemp,
      this.moonPhase,
      this.moonPhaseLunation,
      this.moonriseTs,
      this.moonsetTs,
      this.ozone,
      this.pop,
      this.precip,
      this.pres,
      this.rh,
      this.slp,
      this.snow,
      this.snowDepth,
      this.sunriseTs,
      this.sunsetTs,
      this.temp,
      this.ts,
      this.uv,
      this.validDate,
      this.vis,
      this.weather,
      this.windCdir,
      this.windCdirFull,
      this.windDir,
      this.windGustSpd,
      this.windSpd});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    appMaxTemp = json['app_max_temp'].toDouble();
    appMinTemp = json['app_min_temp'].toDouble();
    clouds = json['clouds'];
    cloudsHi = json['clouds_hi'];
    cloudsLow = json['clouds_low'];
    cloudsMid = json['clouds_mid'];
    datetime = json['datetime'];
    dewpt = json['dewpt'].toDouble();
    highTemp = json['high_temp'].toDouble();
    lowTemp = json['low_temp'].toDouble();
    maxDhi = json['max_dhi'];
    maxTemp = json['max_temp'].toDouble();
    minTemp = json['min_temp'].toDouble();
    moonPhase = json['moon_phase'].toDouble();
    moonPhaseLunation = json['moon_phase_lunation'].toDouble();
    moonriseTs = json['moonrise_ts'];
    moonsetTs = json['moonset_ts'];
    ozone = json['ozone'].toDouble();
    pop = json['pop'];
    precip = json['precip'].toDouble();
    pres = json['pres'].toDouble();
    rh = json['rh'];
    slp = json['slp'].toDouble();
    snow = json['snow'];
    snowDepth = json['snow_depth'];
    sunriseTs = json['sunrise_ts'];
    sunsetTs = json['sunset_ts'];
    temp = json['temp'].toDouble();
    ts = json['ts'];
    uv = json['uv'].toDouble();
    validDate = json['valid_date'];
    vis = json['vis'];
    weather = json['weather'] != null ? Weather.fromJson(json['weather']) : null;
    windCdir = json['wind_cdir'];
    windCdirFull = json['wind_cdir_full'];
    windDir = json['wind_dir'];
    windGustSpd = json['wind_gust_spd'].toDouble();
    windSpd = json['wind_spd'].toDouble();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['app_max_temp'] = appMaxTemp;
    data['app_min_temp'] = appMinTemp;
    data['clouds'] = clouds;
    data['clouds_hi'] = cloudsHi;
    data['clouds_low'] = cloudsLow;
    data['clouds_mid'] = cloudsMid;
    data['datetime'] = datetime;
    data['dewpt'] = dewpt;
    data['high_temp'] = highTemp;
    data['low_temp'] = lowTemp;
    data['max_dhi'] = maxDhi;
    data['max_temp'] = maxTemp;
    data['min_temp'] = minTemp;
    data['moon_phase'] = moonPhase;
    data['moon_phase_lunation'] = moonPhaseLunation;
    data['moonrise_ts'] = moonriseTs;
    data['moonset_ts'] = moonsetTs;
    data['ozone'] = ozone;
    data['pop'] = pop;
    data['precip'] = precip;
    data['pres'] = pres;
    data['rh'] = rh;
    data['slp'] = slp;
    data['snow'] = snow;
    data['snow_depth'] = snowDepth;
    data['sunrise_ts'] = sunriseTs;
    data['sunset_ts'] = sunsetTs;
    data['temp'] = temp;
    data['ts'] = ts;
    data['uv'] = uv;
    data['valid_date'] = validDate;
    data['vis'] = vis;
    if (weather != null) {
      data['weather'] = weather!.toJson();
    }
    data['wind_cdir'] = windCdir;
    data['wind_cdir_full'] = windCdirFull;
    data['wind_dir'] = windDir;
    data['wind_gust_spd'] = windGustSpd;
    data['wind_spd'] = windSpd;
    return data;
  }
}

class Weather {
  String? description;
  int? code;
  String? icon;

  Weather({this.description, this.code, this.icon});

  Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    description = json['description'];
    code = json['code'];
    icon = json['icon'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['description'] = description;
    data['code'] = code;
    data['icon'] = icon;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is my Service

```
import 'package:flutter_weather_app/Model/weather_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class WeatherService {
  final String url =
      'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=Raleigh,NC&key=5cea02af6cd6498d9524cedb8ab23b4c';

  Future<WeatherModel?> fetchWeather() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonBody = WeatherModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return jsonBody;
    } else {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the front end code where I am passing value :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../Model/weather_model.dart';
import '../service/weather_service.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Data>? weatherList = [];

  final WeatherService _service = WeatherService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _service.fetchWeather().then((value) {
      if (value != null && value.data != null) {
        setState(() {
          weatherList = value.data;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('data'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: weatherList?.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(weatherList![index].appMaxTemp.toString()),
            subtitle: Text(weatherList![index].appMaxTemp.toString()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the error I mentioned above and I want to print the cityName data in the model on the screen.
string? cityName;

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why is your `weatherList` nullable, and why does this line: `weatherList = value.data;` even compile?